# Speech emotional recognition on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, emotion

I need to find service or plugin for getting emotional analyze (like emotional list or something) by audio uploading.
Or maybe you can suggest some plugin/service for getting audio details?

Comment: There are many open source projects for emotion recognition. You can just build an api around it and upload it on your server

Comment: @EnviroApps
Sounds good, but ideally I would like to find an easier way)

Comment: Then just Google “api emotion recognition” and you will find a few APIs that just need to be integrated

Comment: lol, it works)) Thank you!
In previous days i trying to find same things but i got nothing

Comment: Glad I could help you